# How can I figure out how many threads cut needs in Snakemake rule?

Tags: bash, bioinformatics, cut, snakemake

I use cut in one rule of my pipeline and always throws an error, but without any error description.
When I try this command with a simple bash script it is working without any errors.

Here is the rule:

```
rule convert_bamheader:
    input: bam/SERUM-ACT/exon_tagged_trimmed_mapped_cleaned.bam, stats/SERUM-ACT/good_barcodes_clean_filter.txt
    output: bam/SERUM-ACT/exon_tagged_trimmed_mapped_cleaned_header.txt, bam/SERUM-ACT/exon_tagged_trimmed_mapped_cleaned_header_filtered.tsv
    jobid: 15
    wildcards: sample=SERUM-ACT
    threads: 4


        mkdir -p stats/SERUM-ACT
        mkdir -p log/SERUM-ACT
        samtools view bam/SERUM-ACT/exon_tagged_trimmed_mapped_cleaned.bam > bam/SERUM-ACT/exon_tagged_trimmed_mapped_cleaned_header.txt
        cut -f 12,13,18,20-24 bam/SERUM-ACT/exon_tagged_trimmed_mapped_cleaned_header.txt | grep -f stats/SERUM-ACT/good_barcodes_clean_filter.txt > bam/SERUM-ACT/exon_tagged_trimmed_mapped_cleaned_header_filtered.tsv

Submitted DRMAA job 15 with external jobid 7027806.
    Error in rule convert_bamheader:
        jobid: 15
        output: bam/SERUM-ACT/exon_tagged_trimmed_mapped_cleaned_header.txt, bam/SERUM-ACT/exon_tagged_trimmed_mapped_cleaned_header_filtered.tsv

ClusterJobException in line 256 of */pipeline.snake:
Error executing rule convert_bamheader on cluster (jobid: 15, external: 7027806, jobscript: */.snakemake/tmp.ewej7q4e/snakejob.convert_bamheader.15.sh). For detailed error see the cluster log.
Job failed, going on with independent jobs.
Exiting because a job execution failed. Look above for error message
Complete log: */.snakemake/log/2018-12-18T104741.092698.snakemake.log
```

I thought that it has to do something with the number of threads provided and number of threads needed for the cut step, but I am not sure.

Perhaps someone can help me?

Cheers!

Comment: I don't think the error has anything to do with the number of threads. I suggest you to find the exact point of failure. Remove the cut line and retry. If it works, add the cut alone, no grep. If it fails, is the cut. If it works, add the grep. Try to discover which is the exact command/parameter/string that makes the command fail. My bets go for the pipe.

Comment: BTW, you should define the commands using the inputs provided in the rule, not with hardcoded strings in the command.

Comment: `For detailed error see the cluster log` - As this says, check your cluster log for this rule to identify the errors. @Poshi - It looks like this is snakemake run's stdout; He may indeed have wildcard based rule construction but is not reflected here as they were resolved during execution.